# Tkinter methods lift(), lower(), deiconify() and geometry() not working (properly or at all) on Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, window-managers, cinnamon

All the following problems apply to Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon (based on Ubuntu 22, using [the muffin window manager](https://github.com/linuxmint/muffin)), while everything works flawlessly on Xubuntu 22.

Please, consider the following steps in a Python3 interpreter:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
```

One can then minimize the widget window either by calling `root.iconify()` or using the window manager's dedicated button for this.

- Problem #1: `root.deiconify()` won't bring the window back on the desktop, it stays minimized.

  - A sub-optimal workaround is `root.withdraw(); root.deiconify()`, but this changes the widgets location on the desktop and also its icon on the taskbar shits to the end.
  - Hint: on Xubuntu, `root.iconify()` executes in no time, while on LM, `root.iconify()` is hanging for a few seconds after minimizing the widget as if it was waiting for something?..

If you don't minimize this window, but move another window of whatever application over it, you face...

- Problem #2: `root.lift()` won't raise it to the top, it stays hidden under the other window.

  - As a workaround, `root.focus_force(); root.lift()` does the job, but it steals the focus. `root.attributes('-topmost', 1); root.attributes('-topmost', 0)` might be a perfect workaround though.

After lifting it, let's say, you want to lower it again...

- Problem #3: `root.lower()` won't do anything. Here too, I am only aware of the sub-optimal workaround with `root.focus_force(); root.lower()`, which leaves the focus on a widget that is not even visible.
- Problem #4: please, consider the script below:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200-0-0')

def func():
    root.geometry('-100-100')
    root.geometry('-0-0')
    print(root.geometry())

b = Button(root, text='push me', command=func)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

On Cinnamon, the first push on the button makes the whole widget jump around 20 pixels up and left, subsequent clicks on the button don't do anything. Nevertheless, it keep printing `200x200-0-0` even though it's obviously not there. The example works with other coordinates too, it doesn't have to be `-0-0`. On Xubuntu, the widget stays in the corner as it is supposed to.

I guess this is not an extensive list of similar issues at least with the newest version of python3-tk (3.10.8-1~22.04) on Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon. I wonder where exactly the problems might hide, since none of these issues appear on Xubuntu 22. I would guess, it has to do with the different window managers.

Any insights and workarounds would be very welcome!

Comment: What windowing system does Linux Mint 21 use? You can always use the windowing system's API to tell it to lower/list/iconify/deiconify the window instead of `tkinter`.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you for the tip. My Linux Mint uses [muffin](https://github.com/linuxmint/muffin). I guess, this could be a way to go, but I'd like my app to work on all Ubuntu based distros independently of their window manager. And at the moment, I have no idea what's the situation with other window managers. So my hope is to find a wm-independent solution.